# Avoiding consent screen using react-oauth and Authorization code flow

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

I'm using Authorization code flow with [react-oauth](https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth). Everything is working in the sense that the user can log in and I get the token and refresh token that I then use for any of my backend API calls that require authentication.

However, the Google auth URL contains the `prompt=consent` parameter which means the user needs to consent to share their info every time instead of just the first time (as I've seen when I implemented Google auth in other platforms).

Looking at the docs for the library, it seems that overriding this setting is not available with the "auth-code" flow. Is there a way to force the parameter to be "select_account" instead?

Here's the code:

```
const Login: FC<LoginProps> = () => {
  const [userImage, setUserImage] = useState("");
  const { setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    flow: "auth-code",
    // prompt: "select_account", -- this doesn't work
    onSuccess: async (codeResponse) => {
      const formData = new URLSearchParams();
      formData.append("code", codeResponse.code);
      const baseUrlApi = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_BASE_API_URL;
      try {
        const tokens = await axios.post(baseUrlApi + "client/login", formData);
        type DecodedToken = {
          name: string;
          picture: string;
        };
        const idToken = tokens.data["id_token"];
        const decodedToken = jwtDecode(idToken) as DecodedToken;

        setUser({
          name: decodedToken.name,
          picture: decodedToken.picture,
          idToken: tokens.data["id_token"],
          accessToken: tokens.data["access_token"],
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  });
```